# How to synchronize data from clickhouse to mysql?

Tags: mysql, clickhouse

I have created a materialized view, I can execute **sql** to get some result through `clickhouse-client`, but how can I save the result data to another mysql database?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [MySQL Database engine](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/database-engines/mysql/):

```sql
CREATE DATABASE db 
ENGINE = MySQL('server:3306', 'database', 'user', 'password')

INSERT INTO db.table VALUES (3,4)
```

See more info here: [Altinity MySQL&CH](https://altinity.com/blog/tag/mysql/).